# Expense aproval send error google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get an expense approval sheet working, most of it now works, but when I submit the script to send the approval results to the user and the sheet. I get following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "approveExpenseReport" from undefined. (line 64)

The error is referencing the below line.

```
var approvedOrRejected = (approval.approveExpenseReport == "Yes") ? "approved" : "rejected";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/expense_report_approval) on Expense Approvals verbatim?

If not, please share more of the code or point to which sample/tutorial you are operating off. Basically, the error message means that the "approval" object instance is not set to a value.

Otherwise, looking at the code from the tutorial, my guess is that you have not properly created the "Approvals Spreadsheet". Perhaps, it doesn't have the right headers and row formats? Make sure to follow the steps in Section #2 in the tutorial.